# Как закрыть Activity через другое Activity

Tags: java, android

Как через активное `Activity` (`MainActivity`) закрыть другое `Activity` (`FirstActivity`), которое находится в "спящем режиме"?

**Обновление**

Классы `MainActivity.java` и `SelectDictionary.java`. Они слишком большие и запутанные, чтобы их сюда закидывать. `SelectDictionary` запускает `ActivityMain`, а `ActivityMain`, проверяет работает ли `SelectDictionary`, если да  - закрывает. Проверка осуществляется через переменные. У меня есть отдельный класс, в котором переменная отвечает за работу `SelectActivity`. `SelectActivity` ставит переменной значение `true`, в методе `onCreate` и `false` - в `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд вы не в том направлении смотрите. Если нужно всего лишь чтобы при запуске MainActivity из SelectDictionary инстанс последней уничтожался то лучше в интент, который вы посылаете для открытия MainActivity добавить пару флагов:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
   intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   startActivity (intent) ;
```

Названия флагов говорят за себя.

Answer (score 0):

1. Передайте `Context` `FirstActivity` на статик переменную из `MainActivity`
2. contextFirstActivity.finish()

попробуйте так

Comment: ох уж эти статики! не лучше ли колбеками пользоваться?

Comment: А как передать?

Comment: @bukashka101 покажите ваши классы, потом могу сказать

Comment: может просто с помощью броадкастресивера?

Comment: @s_klepcha, а что это? :)

Comment: http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/149875/ - про них

Answer (score 0):

Для этого удобно использовать EventBus. Вы просто создаете события, и подписываетесь в нужных `activity` на них, после этого когда с одного `activity` запустили событие, другое `activity`(которое подписалось), увидело что событие вызвалось и совершает нужные ему действия .вот ссылка на github:

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

http://square.github.io/otto/